# laravel 5.4 - how to prevent one's role from being able to access the property of another role?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have an inventory app that has three different roles, namely operator, admin, and super admin.

the problem is when I enter with one of the roles, I can access the menu belongs to another role by writing the link from the menu in the browser's link bar.

**example**

in the admin page there is a backup and restore menu, `link: /admin/backupAndRestore`

then I log in as an operator

in the operator page there is only the item borrowing and return item menu, but if I write a link of the admin backup and restore menu in the browser's link bar like `localhost: 8000/admin/backupAndRestore` I can access the page.

I want to make it like a user who has logged in can not access the register or login page and redirected to the home page, what should I do?

Comment: You can use policies, read the authorization documentation for an idea of how to use that portion of Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are looking for is known as [authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization) in the Laravel framework. Since you can technically implement user roles in many different ways, it is not realistic to post a code example for you here. Instead, I recommend you read the entire documentation page on [authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization) and then devise an implementation that works for your setup. It is most likely that you will want to build your logic using [Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#creating-policies), which are classes that organize authorization logic around a particular model.